# Не работает SQLite запрос с множественным условием WHERE

Tags: python, база-данных, бот, aiogram, sqlite3

Пишу телеграм бота на aiogram, python. Возникла необходимость воспользоваться базой данных, написал следующий запрос:

```
for value in cur.execute("SELECT field FROM vlnt_table WHERE faculty = ? AND university = ?", (faculty_pressed, university_pressed)):
    current_value = str(value)
    fields_list.append(current_value)
```

Однако этот код не работает, выдается ошибка:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Проверял все переменные, соотносил со значениями из базы, пробовал писать два отдельных запроса с каждой из переменных faculty_pressed и university_pressed (они работали), но вот вместе, в одном WHERE, они не работают. Мне нужны именно эти два условия, подскажите, в чем проблема, пожалуйста! Буду рад, если найдется вариант реализации этих условий с помощью двух запросов (мне нужно именно в цикле)

upd: показываю, что я вкладывал в переменные:

```
faculty_pressed = (message.text[10:],)


async with state.proxy() as abit_filter:
    abit_filter['university'] = (message.text[12:],)
university_pressed = abit_filter['university']
```

Вот так я проверял, находятся ли соответствия:

```
for value in cur.execute('SELECT university FROM vlnt_table'):
    print(value)
    if value == university_pressed:
        print('Должно работать!!')
```

Закину, пожалуй, всю функцию:

```
async def cmd_abit_filters_faculty(message: types.Message, state = FSMContext):
async with state.proxy() as abit_filter:
    abit_filter['faculty'] = (message.text[10:],)
    university_pressed = abit_filter['university']
faculty_pressed = (message.text[10:],)
print(abit_filter['university'])
fields_list = []
for value in cur.execute('SELECT university FROM vlnt_table'):
    print(value)
    if value == university_pressed:
        print('Должно работать!!')
for i in cur.execute("SELECT field FROM vlnt_table WHERE (faculty = ?) AND (university = ?)", (faculty_pressed, university_pressed)):
    current_value = str(value)
    current_value = current_value.replace('(', '')
    current_value = current_value.replace(')', '')
    current_value = current_value.replace("'", "")
    current_value = current_value.replace(',', '')
    fields_list.append(current_value)
base.commit()
fields_set = list(set(fields_list))
fields_set = fields_list
kb_fields = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
for i in fields_set:
    kb_fields.add(f"Направление {i}")
await FSMFilters.next()
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите направление подготовки, о котором хотели бы узнать', reply_markup=kb_fields)
```

Comment: в скобки не пробовали ставить: `WHERE (faculty = ?) AND (university = ?)`   ?

Comment: что у вас в `faculty_pressed`? Вы уверены, что ошибка именно в этой строке?

Comment: Да, покажите, что у вас собственно в `faculty_pressed` и `university_pressed`

Comment: @Сергей, скобки не работают

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, обновил вопрос

Comment: Ну вот у вас кортеж в faculty_pressed, и что вы ожидаете что получится, если подставить кортеж?

Comment: @CrazyElf, обновил вопрос

Comment: @CrazyElf, иногда в БД как раз такой кортеж. Вчера похожий был вопрос. Там ещё и срез неверно брали и не проверяли, что в запросе, а что в БД.

Comment: в список должно добавиться значение, оно не добавляется

Comment: что значит "в список должно добавиться значение, оно не добавляется" - в какой список и какое значение?

Comment: самый первый отрывок кода, Сергей

Comment: я функцию полную закинул в вопрос

Comment: На основании вопросов более опытных товарищей выше: а) что у вас собственно в `faculty_pressed` и `university_pressed`?  - конкретное значение какое? Лучше всего через `print (faculty_pressed, university_pressed)` прямо перед запросом `for i in cur.execute`. б) Что в базе записано? Считайте из базы или как-то сами посмотрите. Вчере в аналогичном случае "разбежались" значения.

Comment: ('КБ',) ('МГТУ им. Баумана',) - faculty_pressed, university_pressed
('Петров', 'Петр', 'Петрови', '4', 'Москва', 'МГТУ им. Баумана', 'КБ', 'КБ', '5221447273')
('Петров', 'Валера', 'Альбертович', '4', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'ИТМО', 'ФКТИ', 'ПИ', '5221447273') - это значения из базы данных, вот в частности 6 и 7 значение в первой строке совпадают с переменными

Comment: У меня сильное подозрение, что проверяется равенство кортежа ('КБ',) и кортежа ('Петров', 'Петр', 'Петрови', '4', 'Москва', 'МГТУ им. Баумана', 'КБ', 'КБ', '5221447273'). Результат - несовпадение, что вполне логично. Вы точно получали совпадение, когда половинку тестировали?? (отмечу, что в SQL я практически не разбираюсь, но чудеса в программировании не встречаются обычно).

Comment: @Сергей вы пишете `иногда в БД как раз такой кортеж. Вчера похожий был вопрос.` - нет, вы неправильно интерпретируете, что там происходит, и тот ответ в общем случае неправильный (хоть и, возможно, работает в частном случае для одного элемента). Этот вопрос как раз это и показывает. В базе нет кортежей. Это execute возвращает кортеж - по элементу на колонку, если в результате одна колонка - то возвращает кортеж из одного элемента. Этт то, что вы приняля за "в БД такой кортеж". А `execute` тоже принимает кортеж, и когда у нас один параметр, то это такого же вида кортеж - возникает така путаница

Comment: И впечатление, что хранятся в БД кортежи. А на самом деле - нет.

Comment: Спасибо, подправил там немного. Там получилось, не понимая, как БД работает, помочь, тут - нет. Но я несколько удивлялся, зачем в БД кортежи, теперь ясно стало, что их там и нет. Пора мне учить SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся проблема в том, что вы неправильно используете метод `execute` у курсора, а именно неправильно передаете параметры запроса, т.е. второй параметр функции `execute`.

Если у вас запрос в котором есть несколько параметров т.е. значений, которые вы передаете в запрос и в самом тексте запроса вы их задает знаками вопроса, то второй параметр должен быть списком или кортежем, в котором первому знаку вопроса соответствует значение первого параметра, второму - значение второго  и т.д.

На примере вашего запроса `SELECT field FROM vlnt_table WHERE (faculty = ?) AND (university = ?)`. У вас два параметра (еще по другому называются связываемые переменные, bounded variables). Поля `faculty` и `university` у вас в БД, как я понял, строки. Значит вторым параметром в `execute` нужно передавать список или кортеж из двух строк.

Вы же передаете кортеж из двух элементов, но первым является не строка, а кортеж из одного элемента (например вот `('КБ',)` - это кортеж из одной строки), который вы создаете тут:

```
faculty_pressed = (message.text[10:],)
```

Когда вы делали запрос для одного элемента, то вы передавали этот одноэлементый кортеж, как второй аргумент в `execute`, и это работало потому, что это именно то, что `execute` ждет - список или кортеж из стольких элементов, сколько у вас параметров в запросе (в этом случае 1).

Когда же у вас два параметра, то, как я уже сказал выше, нужно передавать кортеж из двух элементов. В вашем случае это означает, что нужно делать так:

```
faculty_pressed = message.text[10:]
```

Так же нужно убедиться, что `university_pressed` содержит строку со значением из колонки `university` (я все еще не понимаю из ваших ответов, что там за значение и какого оно типа) и тогда такой вызов будет работать, как ожидаете:

```
cur.execute("SELECT field FROM vlnt_table WHERE (faculty = ?) AND (university = ?)", (faculty_pressed, university_pressed))
```

Comment: То есть я подавал кортеж кортежей! Спасибо вам, все работает, я теперь буду знать этот нюанс